# Delphi for...in in C++Builder

Tags: c++builder

Delphi code

```
var
  BookNode, EntityNode: TXmlNode;
  Books: TXmlNodeList;
...
for BookNode in Books do
```

In CLang compiler in C++Builder

`for (auto && BookNode : Books)`

How to write this code in a classic compiler?

The `Count`/`RecordCount`/`Items->Count` e.g. property is missing.

I'm using the classic compiler because some components do not support CLang.

Comment: If `for (auto && BookNode : Books)` compiles with the clang compiler, please show the declaration of `Books`. 1) A `TXmlNodeList` can't be an automatic variable, so `Books` is probably a `TXmlNodeList*`. 2) A `TXmlNodeList` doesn't have `begin()` and `end()` functions. (disclaimer: I'm using C++ Builder 10.3 and it may have had or gotten those member functions before or after 10.3)

Comment: @TedLyngmo "*A TXmlNodeList doesn't have begin() and end() functions*" - in recent versions (ie, from Berlin onwards, IIRC), `range-for` does support various Delphi container types, including those that implement `GetEnumerator()`, or `Count`+`operator[]`. See [C++ Iterator Support for Delphi Enumerable Types and Containers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Iterator_Support_for_Delphi_Enumerable_Types_and_Containers)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Aha, that's nice. I couldn't get `for(auto& book : *books) {}` to compile though: `[bcc64 Error] Unit1.cpp(39): invalid range expression of type 'Xml::Xmldoc::TXMLNodeList'; no viable 'begin' function available
  sysdyn.h(1029): candidate template ignored: could not match 'DynamicArray<T> *' against 'Xml::Xmldoc::TXMLNodeList'
  sysiterator.h(379): candidate template ignored: could not match 'T *' against 'Xml::Xmldoc::TXMLNodeList'
  sysiterator.h(389): candidate template ignored: could not match 'T *' against 'Xml::Xmldoc::TXMLNodeList'`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I don't have access to `GetCount()` or the `__property Count` either. `[bcc64 Error] Unit1.cpp(41): 'Count' is a protected member of 'Xml::Xmldoc::TXMLNodeList'
  Xml.XMLDoc.hpp(86): declared protected here`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't have access to Berlin+ to check the implementation, but Delphi class types are always accessed by pointer, so does `for(auto &book: book)` (no `*` dereference) work for you? That would match with `T*` in the system iterators. Also, `TXMLNodeList` is the implementation class of the `IXMLNodeList` interface. XMLDocument nodes are accessed via the `IXMLNode` interface, you shouldn't be using `TXMLNodeList` directly anyway, use `_di_IXMLNodeList` instead. `Count` and `Nodes[]` are public in `IXMLNodeList`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau "_XMLDocument nodes are accessed via the `IXMLNode` interface_" ... aha :-) I cheated and did this: `decltype(auto) Unprotect(TXMLNodeList* v) { struct UnprotectTXMLNodeList : TXMLNodeList { auto GetCount() const { return TXMLNodeList::Count; } }; return static_cast<UnprotectTXMLNodeList&>(*v); }` ... horrible :-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau `for(auto& book : books) {}` gives a similar message (but too long to put in full in a comment): `[bcc64 Error] Unit1.cpp(39): invalid range expression of type 'Xml::Xmldoc::TXMLNodeList *'; no viable 'begin' function available   sysdyn.h(1029): candidate template ignored: could not match 'DynamicArray<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'Xml::Xmldoc::TXMLNodeList'   sysiterator.h(379): candidate template ignored: requirement 'isSubscriptable<TXMLNodeList>::value' was not satisfied [with T = Xml::Xmldoc::TXMLNodeList] ...`

Answer (score 4):

The classic compiler does not support C++11, so you can't use a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).  You have to use a [traditional `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) instead.

Delphi's `for..in` loop is based on the concept of an *Enumerator* (see [Iteration Over Containers Using For Statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_Statements)).  However, Delphi's `TXMLNodeList` does not implement an Enumerator, so you can't use it in a `for..in` loop.

C++11's range-based `for` loop is based on the concept of *iterators*.  Embarcadero's CLang compilers implement iterators for many Delphi-style containers that implement a `GetEnumerator()` method or `Count`+`operator[]` properties.  See [C++ Iterator Support for Delphi Enumerable Types and Containers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Iterator_Support_for_Delphi_Enumerable_Types_and_Containers).  In the classic compiler, you would have to use such accesses manually, eg:

```cpp
for(Iterator iter = list->begin(); iter != list->end(); ++iter)
{
    ElementType &elem = *iter;
    ...
}
```

```cpp
for(int index = 0; index < list->Count; ++index)
{
    ElementType &elem = (*list)[index]; // or list->Items[index], etc...
    ...
}
```

```cpp
EnumeratorType *enum = list->GetEnumerator();
while (enum->MoveNext())
{
    ElementType elem = enum->Current;
    ...
}
```

Despite your claim, Delphi's `TXMLNodeList` *DOES* have public [`Count`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNodeList.Count) and [`Nodes[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLIntf.IXMLNodeList.Nodes) properties (inherited from the `IXMLNodeList` interface) for indexing through nodes (Delphi's XML framework predates C++11, after all), eg:

```cpp
_di_IXMLNodeList Books;
...
for(int i = 0; i < Books->Count; ++i)
{
    _di_IXMLNode BookNode = Books->Nodes[i];
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**: the above was based on an assumption that you were using [Embarcadero's XML framework](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/XML), which has its own [`TXMLNode`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLNode) and [`TXMLNodeList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLNodeList) classes. Based on your comment that you are actually using [VerySimpleXML](http://blog.spreendigital.de/2014/09/13/verysimplexml-2-0/) instead, which has similarly named classes, I looked at its code and see that its `TXmlNodeList` class derives from Delphi's [`TObjectList<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList) class, which has public [`Count`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Count) and [`Items[]`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Items) properties.  So, you can use those in a `for` loop, eg:

```cpp
TXMLNodeList *Books;
...
for(int i = 0; i < Books->Count; ++i)
{
    TXMLNode *BookNode = Books->Items[i];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm using [VerySimpleXML 2.0](http://blog.spreendigital.de/2014/09/13/verysimplexml-2-0/). `_di_IXMLNodeList Books;` -> [bcc32 Error] Unit1.cpp(25): E2451 Undefined symbol '_di_IXMLNodeList'

Comment: @antarey "*I'm using VerySimpleXML 2.0*" - that is a very important detail you should have provided up front. My answer is based on the assumption that you were using Embarcadero's XML framework instead, which also has `TXmlNode` and `TXmlNodeList` classes. I have updated my answer to account for this new info.